# r studio show plot title in raster layer

Tags: r, plot, program-entry-point, raster, landsat

I would like to plot a raster layer, however the title does not appear.

```
plot(ndwi_18, main= "Calculated NDWI of Landsat 2018 Image")
```

The raster layer is an excerpt of a Landsat 8 image. The result looks like this:

[image: plot]

Any ideas?

Comment: since we dont have the `ndwi_18` object, we can't reproduce the error and help you. provide a way to load `ndwi_18` or try to reproduce the error with a publicly available raster object

Comment: Since you are working in R studio, have you tried adjusting the size of the plotting window?

Comment: Increase the plot area margins: `par(mar=c(5,5,5,5))`